# Interpreting an ACPI error: No handler for Region

Tags: linux, kernel

I started getting ACPI errors on my Ubuntu 22.10 system, which were not there before.

I saw them on mainline kernel 6.2.2 and Ubuntu kernel 5.19.0 too.

```
kernel: [  132.228690] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RTCM] (0000000097ab3aa0) [SystemCMOS] (20220331/evregion-130)
kernel: [  132.228697] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20220331/exfldio-261)
kernel: [  132.228701] 
kernel: [  132.228702] 
kernel: [  132.228702] Initialized Local Variables for Method [_GRT]:
kernel: [  132.228703]   Local1: 0000000001457204 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
kernel: [  132.228706] 
kernel: [  132.228707] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GRT]
```

I do not know how to interpret these.

Can I link those numbers and IDs to a specific device?
There is an RX580 I don't really use in this system, I could pull, and wonder if it could remove ACPI errors?

Looking up exfldio gives me:

**Module Name: exfldio - Aml Field I/O**

Whatever that means.

What is Aml? What field?

What does GRT stand for?

What does RTCM stand for?

So many questions... such a dense error.

OS: Ubuntu 22.10

CPU: 12600k

MB: Asus PRIME Z690M-PLUS D4

BIOS: 1008 01/13/2022

### Update 1

Upgraded BIOS to `2212 12/13/2022` but the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- RTCM = [Intel Real-Time Configuration Manager](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/tcc-tools/developer-guide/2022-2/real-time-configuration-manager-rtcm.html)
- AML = [ACPI Machine Language](https://wiki.osdev.org/AML)
- [exfldio](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/exfldio_8c.html) is a kernel ACPI module
- GRT is an [ACPI method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACPI)

From linked Intel TCC Tools 2022.2 Dev guide:

> RCTM is an EFI application that makes it possible to use software SRAM
> technology on non-virtualized systems. ... RCTM enables [software
> SRAM](https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/642262/Intel_RTS_Software_SRAM_1_0.pdf) *(PDF link)* technology by implementing functionality
> traditionally reserved for a hypervisor. To use software SRAM, you
> must have RTCM or a hypervisor that supports software SRAM.

SW SRAM is aimed at real-time systems. From the linked Intel White Paper, Aug 2021:

> Software SRAM enables developers with a new and innovative way to
> control the contents of cache directly, protecting critical data from
> eviction by noisy neighbors or even threads within the same
> application.

Based on my quick research; how I understand the messages is that the kernel ACPI driver doesn't know what to do with the RTCM functionality in the CMOS. The whole RTCM thing appears to be a new development, and not crucial to the correct functionality of a PC. So if the system's otherwise behaving normally, I think these messages can be safely ignored.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu server, the screen is flooded with those error logs, do you have an suggestions?

Comment: I'm using Pop!_OS 22.04 (which I recently installed a few weeks ago), and my laptop sometimes shows these messages on screen when awaking from suspend. Was wondering if you knew how to fix this @sify